# How do i get widget instance inside a jQuery widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a keyboard widget for a project, i'm extending `$.ui.mouse`. I need click behavior (not triggered by _mouseCapture). I'm having difficulties to get back `this.options` inside it. See code blocks below :

```
$.widget("ui.keyboard", $.ui.mouse, {
    widgetEventPrefix: "keyboard",
    options: {
        [...]
    },
    [...],
    _create : function() {
        this.element.bind('click.'+this.widgetName, this._mouseClick);
    },
    _mouseClick: function(e) {
        // how do i get this.options here
    }
});
```

Is it best to do this :

```
$.widget("ui.keyboard", $.ui.mouse, {
    widgetEventPrefix: "keyboard",
    options: {
        [...]
    },
    [...],
    _create : function() {
        var self = this;
        this.element.bind('click.'+this.widgetName, function(e) { self._mouseClick(e, self); });
    },
    _mouseClick: function(e, self) {
        // how do i get this.options here -> self.options
    }
});
```

Or this :

```
$.widget("ui.keyboard", $.ui.mouse, {
    widgetEventPrefix: "keyboard",
    options: {
        [...]
    },
    [...],
    _create : function() {
        this.element.bind('click.'+this.widgetName, this._mouseClick);
    },
    _mouseClick: function(e) {
        var self = $.data(this, "keyboard");
        // how do i get this.options here -> self.options
    }
});
```

I had trouble with the last one when i try to trigger it manually $.data is not up unless i trigger a click on `this.element` (which is quite logic).

Is there some other ways ? Which one is the best to pick ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call an anonymous function returning an object, like this:

```
$.widget("ui.keyboard", $.ui.mouse, function(){
  var self;

  return {
    widgetEventPrefix: "keyboard",
    options: {
      [...]
    },
    _create : function() {
      self = this;
      this.element.bind('click.'+this.widgetName, function(e) { self._mouseClick(e, self); });
    },
    _mouseClick: function(e, self) {
      // do something with self.options
    }
  }
}());
```

This way you have access to self from within _mouseClick-

Comment: inside `_mouseClick` `this` is the dom element i just clicked. So this.options won't be set.

Comment: It does not seem good practice (i think it may break a lot of inheritance mecanics from $.widget but not sure), both my examples do work in my example, i don't want sth that work, i want best practice advice! Thanks anyway.

Comment: this seems to be a pretty good tutorial: http://bililite.com/blog/understanding-jquery-ui-widgets-a-tutorial/